# How to pass argument to docker container when running docker-compose up

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD . /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.6", "./main.py"]
```

Where main.py takes in run time arguments that are parsed using argparse like so:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('city')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.city)
```

I have succesfully built a docker image from my Dockerfile and run a container based on this image using:

```
docker run -it my-docker-image "los angeles"
```

This works great and argparse in python receives the param "los angeles" as the city in my python code snippet.

I am now trying to accomplish the equivalent of

```
docker run -it my-docker-image "los angeles"
```

But with a docker-compose.yml file. Right now my docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  data-worker:
    image: url-to-my-docker-container-on-ecr-that-i-have-pulled-onto-my-local-machine
    container_name: run-for-city
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws/:/root/.aws
```

I then try running:

```
docker-compose up
```

and it gets started but fails saying:

```
run-for-city | usage: main.py [-h] city
run-for-city | main.py: error: the following arguments are required: city
run-for-city exited with code 2
```

which makes perfect sense as i need to pass the city param when running docker-compose up but don't know exactly how to.

i tried:

```
docker-compose up "los angeles"
```

but that did not work.

Do i need to add something to my docker-compose.yml and or an argument to the docker-compose up command or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Docker terminology, the extra parameter you're passing is a "command".  (Anything after the image name in `docker run` is the command; conventionally it's an actual command to run, but if you have an `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile, it's passed as arguments to the entrypoint.)  You can replicate this in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  data-worker:
    image: 123456789012.dkr...
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws/:/root/.aws
    command: ["los angeles"]  # <--
```

If you need to pass this at the command line, the only real way to do it is via an environment variable.  [Compose will substitute environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) (note, somewhat limited syntax) and I believe it will work to say

```yaml
command: ["$CITY"]
```

and you'd launch this with

```sh
CITY="los angeles" docker-compose up
```